# How to display changed fields in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

I have a model `Managers` and a proxy model `MyManagers`. A am trying to display changed field in Admin panel for proxy model, but `Admin/history` display only user, date and action. How to fix it?

My `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords


class Managers(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
   lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
   enduser_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='', help_text=u"Please enter the end user id, like ABC1WZ1")
   history = HistoricalRecords()

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Manager'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Managers'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + self.lastname

class ManagersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('name','lastname','enduser_id')


class MyManagers(Managers):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.upper() +' '+self.lastname.upper() 

class MyManagersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name', 'lastname','enduser_id']
    list_display = ('name', 'lastname','enduser_id')
    history_list_display = ['name','lastname','enduser_id','changed_fields']

    def changed_fields(self, obj):
        if obj.prev_record:
            var = obj.diff_against(obj.prev_record)
            return var.changed_fields
        return None
```

My `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

# Additional board for assigning a manager to a Department. 
admin.site.register(Managers, ManagersAdmin)
admin.site.register(MyManagers, MyManagersAdmin)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate after making changes in your models?

Comment: yes, when i am trying to execute migrations now i have No changes detected an No migrations to apply.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue , you can use a ModelAdmin method and used History Diffing to add a custom field in the Change history table.

```
history_list_display = ['changed_fields']

def changed_fields(self, obj):
    if obj.prev_record:
        delta = obj.diff_against(obj.prev_record)
        return delta.changed_fields
    return None
```

It worked for me.